# How can I enumerate a sublevel in a multiindex in pandas simply?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index, enumerate

I would like to create a new column with the enumeration of Objects column based on membership in Name

| Name | Objects |
| --- | --- |
| A | phone |
| B | phone |
| B | keys |
| B | chewing gum |
| C | radio |
| C | chewing gum |

into

| Name | Object no. | Objects |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | phone |
| B | 1 | phone |
| B | 2 | keys |
| B | 3 | chewing gum |
| C | 1 | radio |
| C | 2 | chewing gum |

I suppose that there should be a really easy way to do it

Comment: The rows don't match between input and output.

Comment: my bad, updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `groupy` then `cumcount`

```py
df['Object no.'] = df.groupby('Name').cumcount().add(1)
```

```
print(df)

  Name      Objects  Object no.
0    A        phone           1
1    B        phone           1
2    B         keys           2
3    B  chewing gum           3
4    C        radio           1
5    C  chewing gum           2
```